# Is there a way to get asterisks Inputs as justs texts in the database?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with Masked inputs. These inputs goes directly into the database as asterisks (*). Is there a better way to have just text sent to the database? Here is my code below.

```js
$("input[name='maskNum']").on("input", function(e) {
  $("input[name='uDigits']").val(destroyMask(this.value));
  this.value = createMask($("input[name='uDigits']").val());
});

function createMask(string) {
  return string.replace(/[^(\\+|0-9)]/g, '*');
}

function destroyMask(string) {
  return string.replace(/[^(\\+|0-9)]/g, '*');
}
```

These codes mainly create the mask on input finalization. But the asterisks goes into the database. How can i resolve this to get just text in database? Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason you’re not using `<input type="password">`? Other than that, utilize the [`FormData` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes please. I am not using password because i want to control some inputs such as numbers ending as 7364*** and others, right on inputs there. And please, NO API, NO Plugins. Is there any other workaround on this?

Comment: No, `FormData` is a native, built-in API. Saying “No APIs” doesn’t make sense. This isn’t a plugin. As for the “controlled masking”, have you tried using an `<input type="hidden">` which caries the real value?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Ok i will go through the documentation for FormData. But as for inputs=hidden, it renders the input field hidden. disabled

Comment: No, an `<input type="hidden">` is not disabled by default. They specifically exist so that data can be sent without showing the input field.

Comment: Yes, i think i understand what you mean. But, that is not what i intend to use it for. I do not want readonly or any restriction to the input field. But i wonder hpw i can use the hidden to this solution

Comment: Well, you can use the [`input` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) on the visible input to update the `value` property of the hidden input. You can use the same event to mask the input.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you for your help. I am already going through FormData. But please, do you know the lifetime of object in FormData? I am assuming it cannot append data on input because of its lifetime. I might be wrong

Comment: Just to state that i went through the FormData and it was helpful. I fixed it using FormData. Thanks anyway.
well, i had to create a FormData outside the function scode,let fdata = new FormData();
and then i iterate it on another function capturing the OnBlur="function()" to process finalization of data.
    function onblur(){
            var newdata ="";
            for (let [key, value] of fdata.entries()) {
              insidehere += value;
            }
Thanks anyway!